# Mootools 1.3 and Fx.Styles

Tags: javascript, constructor, mootools

I get the following error:

```
Fx.Styles is not a constructor`
```

at line:

```
new Fx.Styles(obj.element, {'duration' : this.options.display.fadeDuration}).start({'opacity':[1]});
```

And what about this one?

```
.scrollTo is not a function
```

Is Fx.Scroll still available?

How could I solve that? I'm running Mootools 1.3.
Thank you.

Comment: no Fx.Styles in mootols 1.3 depreciated

Answer (score 4):

there is **no** Fx.Styles in mootools 1.3

You should use Fx.Morph or Fx.Tween i.e.

```
var myFx = new Fx.Morph(element, {/*options*/});
myFx.start({/*whatever*/});
```

Edit: your code 'renewed'

```
var myFxStyle = new Fx.Morph(obj.element, {'duration' : this.options.display.fadeDuration});
myStyleFx.start({'opacity':1});
```

Comment: How could I replace my code above with Fx.Tween? What's the equivalent?

Comment: @thom check my last edit ;) ..I'm making a working example I'll post on jsfiddle.. brb :P

Comment: Now I get: l.camelCase is not a function... (function(){this.MooTools={version:"1....,2)+"</invoke>");return eval(rs)}})();
mootools-core.js (line 1)

Comment: check this example out http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/F72bH/ ..if you're using mootools > 1.2 it will correctly work.. check out dimitar example too: he explains better the new "FX" features ;)

Answer (score 2):

since 1.2 these have been also available as element shortcuts (as steweb says, Fx.Styles deprecated, so Fx.Tween and Fx.Morph as exported into elements upon request, much easier):

```
element.set("tween", {
    duration: 200,
    onComplete: function() {
        this.element.destroy();
    }
});

element.tween("opacity", newvalue);
// or even use .fade which shortcuts this:

element.fade(0); 
// or
element.fade(.7, 0);
```

similarly:

```
element.set("morph", {
    duration: 200,
    link: "cancel",
    onComplete: function() {
        this.element.destroy();
    }
});

element.morph({
    "opacity": [1,0],
    "marginLeft": [0,-500]
});
```

to access events back, just retrieve the element FX instance:

```
element.get("morph").removeEvents("complete").setOptions({
     // new options...
});
```